# c++ timer , equivalent of .NET System.Threading.Timer

Tags: c++, timer

Does C++ has some built in timer class with same idea as .NET System.Threading.Timer

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.timer.aspx

Or I need to implement it myself ? :-(. Maybe there is some library , plz.

Thanks.

Comment: Most GUI frameworks will have one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Standard C++ does not have one built in.

If you are using the `Win32` API, which seems likely if you are coming from `.NET`, there are various options, such as [`SetTimer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644906%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (which requires a message loop), or [`CreateTimerQueueTimer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682485%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (which does not require a message loop).

As said in the comments, most GUI frameworks will have an asynchronous timer available.

If you are looking for something more generic, or something that doesn't require a GUI framework (like the `Win32` API), you should have a look at [`boost::asio`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/doc/html/boost_asio.html).

Answer (score 1):

Might not be the same but boost has a deadline_timer in asio lib which is quite useful.

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/deadline_timer.html

Answer (score 0):

No, C++ has no Timer class in the language with an interface like System.Threading.Timer.

You compared the language C++ with the .NET runtime library. But you may find a good library that includes a Timer implementation. Boost is a good candidate.